# Оптимизация многофункционального сайта

Tags: laravel, оптимизация, изображения

Добрый день. Имею многофункциональный сайт. Подумываю об оптимизации, так как сайт грузит > 5 секунд, что не есть хорошо. На сайте используются как изображения со своего сервера, так и из чужого. Возможности перенести все изображения к себе нету, так как их больше 4000 (конечно на странице используются не все). Испробовал кеширование, сжатие своих изображений, cloudflare, минимизирование js, css. Все равно скорость никак не устраивает, может есть какие-нибудь еще методы? Ах, да, использую фреймворк Laravel

Comment: Я не могу понять причем тут фото с другого сервера и скорость отдачи страницы сервером ? Может распишете как то подробнее ? что у вас происходит? Вы пользуетесь barryvdh/laravel-debugbar ? что у вас там по запросам к базе  ?

Comment: При том, что эти картинки отображаются у меня на сайте.

Comment: **barryvdh/laravel-debugbar** им не пользуюсь, скорость ответа от сервера ~3 секунды, далее 3 секунды занимает загрузка стилей, скриптов и картинок

Comment: Клиент вообще не должен тянуть картинки и скрипты, которые он ранее уже загружал и которые на сервере не менялись. И это на большинстве web-серверов автоматом происходит если ссылки статические. И формирование страницы 3 сек в никакие ворота не лезет, надо анализировать код серверной части приложения для уменьшения времени формирования страницы

Comment: @Mike Какая оптимальная скорость загрузки не статической страницы?

Comment: В PageSpeed Insights прописано что на сайте не используется кеширование, что очень странно, так как кеширование 100% присутствует

Comment: Поставь компонент запусти Debugbar посмотри где у тебя косяки с запросами, 3 секунды это жесть. Смотри может не настроен сервер, nginx если стоит посмотри как настроена отдача файлов, там отклик должен быть мгновенный пару милесекунд

Comment: @Orange_shadow уменьшил до 430мс отклик сервера, это нормально?

Comment: Ну если с 3-х секунд, стало 430 мс то конечно лучше :) Осталось тебе с запросами поработать

Comment: @Orange_shadow Спасибо. Единственное долго грузит запрос с подсчетом количества записей в таблице, записей больше 60000 и каждый раз добавляются новые, как то можно такой запрос оптимизировать?

Comment: А он вам так жизненно необходим ? нельзя ли выполнить эту инфу после загрузки страницы при помощи ajax запроса и кэшировать этот запрос ну минут на 10 хотя бы ? или вам прям так важна точность ? тогда бы я посоветовал по тригеру в какую нить другу таблицу класть кол-во :) строк, и еще вопрос а та таблица проиндексированна по полю которому вы подсчет ведете или фильтруте ?

Comment: @Orange_shadow Напишите пожалуйста свой ответ отдельно, я его выделю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Поставить barryvdh/laravel-debugbar для происка "долгих" запросов

2) Проверить настройки сервера, особено как отдается статические файлы

3) Если есть "тяжелые" запросы решить эту проблему одним из способов:

- кэшировать запрос на допустимый промежуток
- вынести по возможности часть код связанную с этими данными, в отдельный запрос, после отображения страницы.
- также проверить индексацию таблицы по тем столбцам которым производится фильтрация и подсчет кол-ва
- или же создать таблицу с данными, которые будут хранить значения таких запросов, но обновляться по тригеру изменения в этих таблицах

Comment: Снова обращаюсь к вам )

Столкнулся опять с этой проблемой, у юзера, который первый раз заходит на сайт очень долго грузится страница, понять не могу почему так происходит. Очищаю кеш, захожу на сайт 1-2 секунды и страница загружена. А у остальных минимум секунд 10

Проблема глобальная, где то у половины новых пользователей такая проблема. Какие еще могут быть варианты?

Comment: А сколько весят у вас ваши скрипты? Запросы вы смотрели ? попробуйте в настроках БД выставить логирование [длинных запросов](https://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%B2+MySQL%3F).

Comment: 2.6 мб

У меня нету длинных забросов (если я сброшу весь кеш), так как повторюсь проблема не у всех

Comment: Изображения занимают 1.6 мб, а убрать их возможности нету

Comment: Не пойму, а ты что изображения отдаешь через путь ? ну в плане не напрямую ? и через file_get_contents ? почему изображения то тормозят систему ? или ты их уменьшаешь на ходу ? что с ними не так ?

Comment: На прямую, через src
Большую часть сайта по весу занимают картинки, сейчас стараюсь по максимуму оптимизировать их, посмотрим какие рузультаты будут

Comment: Очень долго сервер отдает ответ по картинкам
https://gyazo.com/41a55d836f486cc09271005e8741822f

Comment: Тут бы помощь админов, у тебя сервер почему то отдавать начинает инфу ток через пару секунд, timline посмотри, у меня сервер отдачу начал через 2800 мс

Comment: Может из-за cloudflare?

Comment: Вот тут не скажу :(, но явно нужно проверять, почему так долго отдача идет

Comment: @llya78rus Насчет быстрого подсчета числа записей, наткнулся на [это](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069237/fastest-way-to-count-exact-number-of-rows-in-a-very-large-table)